# How to edit, delete and add for the following script?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

**Here i fetch product details from json using jquery ajax also i have created add , modify , delete button now *i would like to implement functionality like add, edit, delete operation* and updated value should send to server WITHOUT RELOADING PAGE.**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>Single page application</title>
                <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="clearfix header">
                        <div class="pull-left col-md-4">
                            <h2 data-bind="text:fullTagline"></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left col-md-4">
                            <div class="header-menu clearfix">
                                <button id="add_Prod" type="button" class="button_style blue">Add New Product</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left col-md-4">
                            <input type="button" class="button_style blue space " value="Screen 1" />
                            <input type="button" class="button_style blue" value="Screen 2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"  data-bind="foreach: { data: starList, as: 'category' }">
                        <div class="col-md-6 box-style" >
                            <div class=" clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" data-bind="attr:{'src': 'images/'+$data.imgname+'.jpeg'}" />
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <br />
                                        <button data-bind="click: $root.editItem" type="button" class="button_style">Modify Product</button>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <button data-bind="click: $root.deleteItem" type="button" class="button_style blue">Remove Product</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>TV Name - </strong>
                                        <span  data-bind="text:category.name" ></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>Model - </strong>
                                        <span  data-bind="text:category.model" ></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>Price - </strong>
                                        <span  data-bind="text:category.price" ></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>Description - </strong>
                                        <span  data-bind="text:category.description" ></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong> Features</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: features, as: 'feature' }">
                                        <li>
                                            <b data-bind="text: feature"></b>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="addProduct_wrap ">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <h2 class="pull-left">Add New Product</h2>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default red pull-right cancel-overlay">X</button>
                        </div>
                        <form class="clearfix">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name of the product:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="model">Model No:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="price">Price</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="descr">Comment:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="descr"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default blue pull-left">Save Data</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default blue pull-right">Reset Data</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script src="js/customJS.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

**//KNOCKOUT SCRIPT**

```
function stareDataModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.tagline = ko.observable("Single Page");
    self.hint = ko.observable("Application");
    self.fullTagline = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.tagline() + " " + self.hint();
    });

    var question = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'type': 'GET',
            'global': false,
            'dataType': "json",
            //'url': "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php",
            //'url': "json/serverdata.json",
            'url': "json/records.json",
            'success': function (data) {
               // alert(data)
                // json = JSON.stringify(data);

                //var plainJs = ko.toJS(data);
                json = data;
               // alert(plainJs + "nnmasbdmanbs")
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
        });

        return json;
      //  alert(json)
    })();
   // alert(question);
    self.starList = ko.observableArray(question);

};
ko.applyBindings(new stareDataModel());
```

**jSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Vu 109cm (43) Full HD LED TV",
        "model": "43D6575, 2 x HDMI, 1 x USB",
        "price": "₹ 24,989",
        "imgname":"vu",
        "description":"Use a Stabilizer to protect your Television, in case there are Regular Voltage Fluctuation in your Location, TV Unit, Power Cable, Remote Control, Battery, Manual, Table Stand, Wall Mount Bracket",
        "features": ["Full HD", "1920 x 1080 Resolution","178 degree Viewing Angle","14 Speaker Output", "1 Year Onsite Warranty"]

    },
    {
        "name": " Micromax 102cm (40) Full HD LED TV",
        "model": "43D6575, 2 x HDMI, 1 x USB",
        "price": "₹ 45,989",
        "imgname":"micromax",
        "description":"Use a Stabilizer to protect your Television, in case there are Regular Voltage Fluctuation in your Location, TV Unit, Power Cable, Remote Control, Battery, Manual, Table Stand, Wall Mount Bracket",
        "features": ["Full HD", "1920 x 1080 Resolution","178 degree Viewing Angle","14 Speaker Output", "1 Year Onsite Warranty"]

    },
    {
        "name": "SAMSUNG 102cm (40) Full HD Smart LED TV",
        "model": "40J5300, 2 x HDMI, 2 x USB",
        "price": "₹ 36,989",
        "imgname":"samsung",
        "description":"Use a Stabilizer to protect your Television, in case there are Regular Voltage Fluctuation in your Location, TV Unit, Power Cable, Remote Control, Battery, Manual, Table Stand, Wall Mount Bracket",
        "features": ["Full HD", "1920 x 1080 Resolution","178 degree Viewing Angle","14 Speaker Output", "1 Year Onsite Warranty"]

    },
    {
        "name": "SONY 82cm (32) Full HD Smart LED TV",
        "model": "233423s, 2 x HDMI, 3 x USB",
        "price": "₹ 38,989",
        "imgname":"sony",
        "description":"Use a Stabilizer to protect your Television, in case there are Regular Voltage Fluctuation in your Location, TV Unit, Power Cable, Remote Control, Battery, Manual, Table Stand, Wall Mount Bracket",
        "features": ["Full HD", "1920 x 1080 Resolution","178 degree Viewing Angle","14 Speaker Output", "1 Year Onsite Warranty"]

    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code as follows

In the model create new methods as follows

```
self.AddStuff = function(){
starList.push(
{
'name':$('#name').val(),
//add other properties here
}
);
}

self.delete = function(item){
starList.remove(item);
}

self.update = function(item){
$('#name').val(item.name); // and other properties
}
```

And bind them to respective buttons.
This is only a pseudo code to give you an idea. Go ahead and try it out.